# Manually increase PostgreSQL's table size limit of 32 TB?

Tags: postgresql, database-size

I need a free database software and thought of PostgreSQL. But then I read it has a table size limit of 32 terabytes, but I need more (and don't want to spend thousand/millions on high end database software like Oracle).

Is there a way to manually increase that limit? And if so, what is the penalty for doing so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use a different setting for the [block size](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html):

> --with-blocksize=BLOCKSIZE
>
> The default, 8 kilobytes, is suitable for most situations; but other
>   values may be useful in special cases. The value must be a power of 2
>   between 1 and 32 (kilobytes).

Using 32 kilobytes, your table has a maximum size of 128TB.

Comment: Note that non-default block sizes aren't as well tested, though. Bugs have cropped up before.

Answer (score 14):

Frank's answer is entirely correct, but there's more to it.

**Don't do this**. [Partition your table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) instead. PostgreSQL's table partitioning isn't wonderful, but it's going to be better than a 32TB+ table.

Comment: This question is now 6 years old i wonder if this is still a thing? Increasing the block-size seems less overhead compared to table partinioning.

Comment: @goulashsoup Actually because of the costs involved in huge b-tree indexes, it's usually cheaper to partition.